# How to tell Thymeleaf to populate Password fields?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I use Thymeleaf in a Spring Boot application. The following form works fine, except that the password field won't get populated in case the form's dto won't pass validation:

```java
<form id="registration-form" method="post" th:object="${registrationDto}"
                                           th:action="@{/registration}">

    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" th:field="*{name}"/>

    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" th:field="*{password}"/>

</form>
```

So when the server-side validation fails, the registration template gets shown again and the properties of the registrationDto bound to the form are already set (with at least one of them incorrect). Thymeleaf populates text-fields as expected, but fields of `type="password"` won't get prepopulated. I've tried to add `th:value` but that didn't help.

The generated HTML looks like this:

```java
<input id="password" type="password" name="password" value=""/>
```

Just for information, the password itself gets passed to the form, since it is possible to obtain it for example like that:

```java
<p th:text="*{password}"/>
```

My question therefore is: **How can I get Thymeleaf to populate password fields as well?**

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like?

Comment: Hi @RoToRa, the password input field looks like this: `<input id="password" type="password" name="password" value=""/>`. FYI: the password gets passed to the form since I can obtain it separately for example like `<p th:text="*{password}"/>`. So for whatever reason, Thymeleaf decides just to not put it into fields whose type is password.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up currently with is the following solution:

```java
<form id="registration-form" method="post" th:object="${registrationDto}"
                                           th:action="@{/registration}">

    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" th:field="*{name}"/>

    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" th:value="*{password}"/>

</form>
```

This seems to work and I believe, that Thymeleaf will omit extra checking when you omit to specify the field explicitly via `th:field`. As long as the `name` property matches the form's dto property properly^^ Thymeleaf is still able to map the fields correctly.

I can't say if that's the best solution, but at least it's one that works.